# Group of Order $5$ Generated by $(1,2,3,4,5)$

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading *Algebraic Combinatorics* by Richard P. Stanley and had a quick question about some verbiage:

"Let $G$ be the group of order $5$ generated by the cycle (1,2,3,4,5)"

Doesn't this cycle generate $S_5$ which has order $120$? What group would it be with order $5$? What does this group look like?

Comment: Why would it generate $S_5$? The group consists of the powers of that cycle: the cycle, the square, which is $(1,3,5,2,4)$; the cube, which is $(1,4, 2,5, 3)$, etc.

Comment: Cycles are cyclic.

Comment: Also... there’s only one group of order $5$; so that’s what it looks like.

Comment: @WillJagy: Huh? I’m not sure what you are trying to tell me...

Comment: @Arturo I think I'm lacking some kind of understanding here. How would you square this cycle? Isn't it saying that 1 goes to 1, 2 goes to 2, 3 goes to 3, 4 goes to 4, 5 goes to 5? How do you get the results that you obtained?

Comment: @sfs2007: No, it’s a cycle, not one-line notation. If that were really the permutation in question, then your group would be **trivial** (consisting only of the identity), definitely not $S_5$, so if that were an accurate understanding of the notation, your conclusion  would be even more wildly inaccurate. This is a cycle: it sends $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $4$, $4$ to $5$, and $5$ to $1$. Look up “cycle notation”.

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes... so? When did I say something different?

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes. So take your permutation and apply it twice. After sending $1$ to $2$, it then sends $2$ to $3$; so $1$ maps to $3$. After applying it once to $3$, it sends it to $4$; apply it again and you end up in $5$. So the square sends $3$ to $5$. The square sends $5\mapsto 1\mapsto 2$. The square sends $2\mapsto 3\mapsto 4$. And the square sends $4\mapsto5\mapsto 1$. So in cycle notation, if $\tau=(1,2,3,4,5)$, then $\tau^2=(1,3,5,2,4)$. Again... what is the disagreement/error/confusion?

Comment: I learned cycle notation and got the following group: is it correct? $$\{ (12345), (13524), (14253), (15432), (11111) \}$$ where $(11111)$ represents the identity (I don't know how to represent it in cycle notation - when I did the multiplication, I got all $1$'s).

Comment: @sfs2007: The identity is the empty cycle, $()$, or $\mathrm{id}$. You couldn’t possibly get “all $1$s” because that’s not a permutation. Yes, those are the elements of the subgroup generated by the original permutation. Which is a group of order $5$. Which is necessarily the cyclic group of order $5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one group of order  $5$: the cyclic one.  One can think in terms of  $\mathbb Z_5:=\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z $.  That's the additive group of integers $\bmod5$.

If you're thinking  of $S_5$, then the cycle $(12345) $ has order $5$.  Thus it generates a copy of the cyclic group of order  $5$.  That is $\langle (12345)\rangle \cong C_5$, as it is also denoted.

---

In general,  an element $a $ of order  $n $ in a group $G $ generates a cyclic group of order  $n $:  $\langle a\rangle\cong C_n\le G$.

---

Also there's only one group of order any given prime (up to isomorphism), and it's cyclic